# Change table row color depending on multiple selections/hide elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, checkbox

I have a table. On each row I have a checkbox to "select it", two select boxes and an extra checkbox.

When I show my page, each row background color is the default one (white).

What I need is two things:

1. For each "Action" select box value, I want the row to change its color but only if the row checkbox is checked - Green for 'create' and Red for 'delete'
2. If the "Action" select box value is equal 'delete', I want the second select box and the extra checkbox to be disabled.

At the moment, I have the following code that changes the row background color depending only on the first select box choice, not taking into account the state of the checkbox.

How can I implement this? I don't know how to make these conditions work together.

Thanks.

NOTE: I'm using this code in Drupal but it's generic.
SECOND NOTE: This is used in drupal so I'm using a theme that has already css for the table. When I hover for example and for odd/even rows, some colors are already being applied. Don't know if this has impact on the code to implement what I need.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<table class="containers_table sticky-enabled table-select-processed tableheader-processed sticky-table">
 <thead><tr><th class="select-all"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" title="Select all rows in this table"></th><th>Container</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Action</th><th>Configuration</th><th>scripts</th> </tr></thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="odd"><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-containers-table-VT-1">
  <input class="containers_table form-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-containers-table-vt-1" name="containers_table[VT_1]" value="VT_1">
</div>
</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);">container 1</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);">a</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);">b</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);">c</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-action-VT-1">
  <label class="element-invisible">Action for VT_1 </label>
 <select class="update-action form-select chosen-processed" name="action[VT_1]" style="display: none;"><option value="create">create</option><option value="delete">delete</option></select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single update-action form-select chosen-processed" title="" style="width: 300px;"><a class="chosen-single">
  <span>create</span>
  <div><b></b></div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
    <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
</div></div>
</div>
</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-card-configuration-VT-1">
  <label class="element-invisible">Card configuration for VT_1 </label>
 <select class="update-card_configuration form-select chosen-processed" name="card_configuration[VT_1]" style="display: none;"><option value="default">default</option><option value="HalSim_VT_1_OCC2">HalSim_VT_1_OCC2</option><option value="HalSim_VT_2_OCC2">HalSim_VT_2_OCC2</option><option value="HalSim_VT_3_OCC2">HalSim_VT_3_OCC2</option></select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single update-card_configuration form-select chosen-processed" title="" style="width: 300px;"><a class="chosen-single">
  <span>default</span>
  <div><b></b></div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
    <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
</div></div>
</div>
</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-ne-configuration-VT-1">
  <label class="element-invisible">NE configuration for VT_1 </label>
 <input class="update-ne_configuration form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ne_configuration[VT_1]" value="1">
</div>
</td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-containers-table-VT-2">
  <input class="containers_table form-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-containers-table-vt-2" name="containers_table[VT_2]" value="VT_2">
</div>
</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);">container 2</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);">d</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);">e</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);">f</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-action-VT-2">
  <label class="element-invisible">Action for VT_2 </label>
 <select class="update-action form-select chosen-processed" name="action[VT_2]" style="display: none;"><option value="create">create</option><option value="delete">delete</option></select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single update-action form-select chosen-processed" title="" style="width: 300px;"><a class="chosen-single">
  <span>create</span>
  <div><b></b></div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
    <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
</div></div>
</div>
</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-card-configuration-VT-2">
  <label class="element-invisible">Card configuration for VT_2 </label>
 <select class="update-card_configuration form-select chosen-processed" name="card_configuration[VT_2]" style="display: none;"><option value="default">default</option><option value="HalSim_VT_1_OCC2">HalSim_VT_1_OCC2</option><option value="HalSim_VT_2_OCC2">HalSim_VT_2_OCC2</option><option value="HalSim_VT_3_OCC2">HalSim_VT_3_OCC2</option></select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single update-card_configuration form-select chosen-processed" title="" style="width: 300px;"><a class="chosen-single">
  <span>default</span>
  <div><b></b></div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
    <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
</div></div>
</div>
</td><td style="background-color: rgb(215, 234, 217);"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-ne-configuration-VT-2">
  <label class="element-invisible">NE configuration for VT_2 </label>
 <input class="update-ne_configuration form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ne_configuration[VT_2]" value="1">
</div>
</td> </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleColorRows = {
        attach: function(context) {

            // Bind change event to select
            $('.update-action').change(function(){
                setColors();
            });

            $('.edit-containers-table-groove-vt-1').change(function(){
                setColors2();
            });

            // Call function on first page load
            setColors();

            function setColors() {
                // Loop rows
                $('.containers_table tr').each(function(){
                    // Get color from value of select
                    var color = $(this).find('.update-action').val() == 'create' ? '#D7EAD9' : '#F5BE8B';
                    // Set color
                    $(this).find('td').css({'background-color': color});

                });
            }

            function setColors2() {
                // Loop rows
                $('.containers_table tr').each(function(){
                    // Get color from value of select
                    var color = '#F5BE8B';
                    // Set color
                    $(this).find('td').css({'background-color': color});

                });
            }
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you please also show us the html? Is it just a standard table?

Comment: I added the html code. It's very standard besides having select boxes on each row.

Comment: Is it auto-generated by another library? (because of the in-line css) If not, that makes it a lot easier

Comment: Well, yes... I'm using drupal and the table is generated from a custom module made by me. I get the data and create the table dinamically. That's why I have custom names in the HTML.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with drupal, but if you are the author of the module, you can change the in-line css to classes, right?

Comment: Can you include the colors you want? together with the actions

Answer (score 5):

You have to bind change event to both `select` and `checkbox`. Then

1. Use `$(this).closest('tr')` to get parent `tr` in change event.
2. Use `$tr.find('.containers_table').is(':checked')` to find first
   checkbox status and consider it when changing color.
3. Use `$tr.find('.update-card_configuration, .update-ne_configuration')` to find extra `select` & `checkbox`. And enable/disable these using `prop()` method depending on action value.

```js
var Drupal = function() {};
Drupal.behaviors = function() {};

(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleColorRows = {
    attach: function(context) {

      // Bind change event to select
      $('.update-action, .containers_table').change(function() {
        // Get color from value of select & checkbox
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
          color = '#F5BE8B',
          value = $tr.find('.update-action').val(),
          status = $tr.find('.containers_table').is(':checked');

        if (value == 'create' && status)
          color = '#D7EAD9';

        //enable/disable extra select box and checkbox
        $tr.find('.update-card_configuration, .update-ne_configuration').prop('disabled', value == 'delete');

        // Set color
        $tr.css('background-color', color);
      });

      //call event on first page load
      $('.update-action').change();
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleColorRows.attach();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="containers_table sticky-enabled table-select-processed tableheader-processed sticky-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="select-all">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </th>
      <th>Container</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Configuration</th>
      <th>scripts</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="containers_table" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>container 1</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>
        <label>Action for VT_1 </label>
        <select class="update-action">
          <option value="create">create</option>
          <option value="delete">delete</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Card configuration for VT_1 </label>
        <select class="update-card_configuration">
          <option value="default">default</option>
          <option value="HalSim_VT_1_OCC2">HalSim_VT_1_OCC2</option>
          <option value="HalSim_VT_2_OCC2">HalSim_VT_2_OCC2</option>
          <option value="HalSim_VT_3_OCC2">HalSim_VT_3_OCC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>NE configuration for VT_1 </label>
        <input class="update-ne_configuration" type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="containers_table" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>container 2</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>
        <label>Action for VT_2 </label>
        <select class="update-action">
          <option value="create">create</option>
          <option value="delete">delete</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Card configuration for VT_2 </label>
        <select class="update-card_configuration">
          <option value="default">default</option>
          <option value="HalSim_VT_1_OCC2">HalSim_VT_1_OCC2</option>
          <option value="HalSim_VT_2_OCC2">HalSim_VT_2_OCC2</option>
          <option value="HalSim_VT_3_OCC2">HalSim_VT_3_OCC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>NE configuration for VT_2 </label>
        <input class="update-ne_configuration" type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Azim. Unfortunately that is not working with my code. On top of that, I don't want the rows to be orange when no checkboxes are selected.

Comment: I added some extra `js` to make the code workable in snippet. You just need to replace the code of `attach` function. 
And this is the color I get from your code. Anyway use your color instead of mine. @zephirus

Comment: I'm trying to use my original code and add the logic you gave on your answer. I noticed that the variable 'value' is set as 'create' correctly. But when I change the select box to 'delete' I get 'create' also, not delete. This is very strange. Can we get in touch in any other way?

Comment: So. you still getting the `select` value as `create` always? @zephirus

Comment: yes. I'm thinking about changing everything and start from scratch... I think in this case I need help from someone who does this but in drupal.

Answer (score 3):

**I found a solution for you:**

```
    $(document).on('blur, keyup', '.update-action .chosen-search-input', function () {
//$(document).on('change', '.update-action', function () { // For select option
        var specipicValue = 'test'//this is just specific value
        var value = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).val()) {
            if ($(this).parents('tr').find('.form-checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parents('tr').find('td').css("color", "red");                
            }
            else{
                $(this).parents('tr').find('td').css("color", "unset");  
            }
            if (value == specipicValue) {
                    $(this).parents('tr').find('.update-card_configuration').find('.chosen-search-input').prop("disabled", true);
                    $(this).parents('tr').find('.update-ne_configuration').attr("disabled", true);
                }
            else{
                $(this).parents('tr').find('.update-card_configuration').find('.chosen-search-input').prop("disabled", false);
                    $(this).parents('tr').find('.update-ne_configuration').attr("disabled", false);
            }
        }

    });
```

**Here is preview link:**https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/NwbKZK

*_if you need more customization please let me _* I used for input on 'keyup & in blur', if you use dropdown select you can use 'click'. or let me know for modification.

Comment: I get this error on line 1: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function. When no row is clicked, the table should show the default css. Only if checked must show gree or red depending on the update-action value. Also, the codepen preview does nothing.

Comment: try write on action texbox, see what happend

Comment: I implement this two things, that you mention in your question.
`

    For each "Action" select box value, I want the row to change its color but only if the row checkbox is checked.

    If the "Action" select box value is equal to some specific value, I want the second select box and the extra checkbox to be disabled.
'

Comment: Ok, it changes the labels to red but that's not what I need. I need to change the row background color and is not on click. Is depending on the current selection. Also, the js file gives me an error when I use it in drupal. You can add me on skype if you want: zephiruspt@gmail.com

Comment: I think the main problem here is that I need to override the current css applied to the table. What I mean is that I already have some css working when I hover the rows, when is selected and so on. The behaviour I'm implementing on top is not overriding the default one.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of a row template is suitable only if you do not intend to use hierarchy, grouping, and editing columns. the Grid does not support the simultaneous application of these features and row templates. The approach directly adds template expressions to the rowTemplate and altRowTemplate definitions and determines which custom CSS classes will be applied to a given row or cell.

```
<style>
  .k-grid {
    width: 500px;
  }

  .discontinued {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f00;
  }
  .critical {
    background-color: #fdd;
  }

  .warning {
    background-color: #fda;
  }

  .ok {
    background-color: #ced;
  }

</style>


<div id="grid-rowtemplate"></div>
<script>
  // sample datasource
  var products = [
    { ID: 1, ProductName: "Foo", UnitsInStock: 9, Discontinued: false },
    { ID: 2, ProductName: "Bar", UnitsInStock: 16, Discontinued: false },
    { ID: 3, ProductName: "Baz", UnitsInStock: 3, Discontinued: true }
  ];


  var rowTemplateString = '<tr class="#: Discontinued ? "discontinued" : "" #" data-uid="#: uid #">' +
      '<td>#: ProductName #</td>' +
      '<td class="#: getUnitsInStockClass(UnitsInStock) #">#: UnitsInStock #</td>' +
      '<td>#: Discontinued #</td>' +
      '</tr>';

  var altRowTemplateString = rowTemplateString.replace('tr class="', 'tr class="k-alt ');

  function getUnitsInStockClass(units) {
    if (units < 5) {
      return "critical";
    } else if (units < 10) {
      return "warning";
    } else {
      return "ok";
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid-rowtemplate").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        data: products,
        schema: {
          model: {
            id: "ID",
            fields: {
              ID: { type: "number" },
              ProductName: { },
              UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
              Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      sortable: true,
      columns: [
        { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
        { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px" },
        { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px" }
      ],
      rowTemplate: rowTemplateString,
      altRowTemplate: altRowTemplateString
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How can I apply that to Drupal, Joseph?